# Writing a non-date type in an <input /> date

Tags: html, bootstrap-datepicker

Using **Datepicker for Bootstrap v1.9.0**

I need to select week by year (in the format **WW/YYYY**), I have the following code:

**html**

```
<div class="form-group col-12">
    <label asp-for="EngineeringChange.FinishedGood.Week">Semana</label>
    <input type="text" id="weeklyDatePicker" class="form-control" placeholder="Select Week" />
    <input asp-for="EngineeringChange.FinishedGood.Week" class="form-control weeklyDatePicker" placeholder="Select Week" type="hidden" />
    <span asp-validation-for="EngineeringChange.FinishedGood.Week" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    moment.locale('en', {
        week: { dow: 0, doy: 0 }
        // Sunday is the first day of the week
    });

    //Initialize the datePicker(I have taken format as mm-dd-yyyy, you can     //have your own)
    $("#weeklyDatePicker").datepicker({
        format: 'MM-DD-YYYY'
    });

    //Get the value of Start and End of Week
    $('#weeklyDatePicker').on('changeDate', function (e) {

        var week = moment(e.date, "MM-DD-YYYY").week();
        var year = moment(e.date, "MM-DD-YYYY").year();
        var end = week + '/' + year;
        $("#weeklyDatePicker").val(end);
        console.log(end + "AFTER: " + $("#weeklyDatePicker").val());
    });
});
```

I can get it working as such:
[image]
But as soon as I close the picker, it automatically changes to this:
[image]

I believe this is because `#weeklyDatePicker` is of the type date, but what is the workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the option `forceParse:false` will stop the conversion.

```
$("#weeklyDatePicker").datepicker({
    ...
    forceParse: false,
});
```

**PS:** On a sidenote, what I find strange is that if I change the code to (and before the `forceParse:false` changes):

```
$('#weeklyDatePicker').on('changeDate', function (e) {

    console.log("BEFORE" + $(".weeklyDatePicker").val());

    var week = moment(e.date, "MM-DD-YYYY").week();
    var year = moment(e.date, "MM-DD-YYYY").year();
    var end = week + '/' + year;
    $("#weeklyDatePicker").val("" + end);

    console.log(end + "AFTER: " + $("#weeklyDatePicker").val());

});
```

The `BEFORE` and `AFTER` print will be correct, but the display will not. Meaning if I select a week and close the datapicker, it unintentionally changes to `dd/mm/yyyy` format, but when I open it again the `BEFORE` print will show the correct value (`ww/yyyy`), meaning the value of the input is indeed what I want, but for some reason it changed it's display.